# How did the snowball fly out of the holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, holodeck, jean-luc-picard

In the "Star Trek: The Next Generation" Episode "Angel One" How did Wesley's snowball fly outside of the holodeck and hit Picard? It should have dematerialized.

Answer (score 0):

In Encounter at Farpoint Data tells Riker that much of what they interact with in the holodeck is in fact replicated matter and not holograms.

> RIKER: I didn't believe these simulations could be this real.
>   DATA:Much of it is real, sir. If the transporters can convert our bodies to
>   an energy beam, then back to the original pattern again
>   RIKER: Yes, of course. And these rocks and vegetation have much simpler patterns.

In the same scene Wesley falls in stream and is still sopping wet when he leaves the holodeck.

> WESLEY: Sir, maybe I should get something to wipe this water up.
>
> PICARD: Good idea.

And from Memory Alpha's [Holodeck](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Holodeck) page:

> In the early 24th century, matter replication was primarily used for
>   objects and characters that would be in direct contact with the
>   occupants which gave them an extreme sense of realism. Water, for
>   example, would feel like actual water because on some level, it was,
>   and it could create experiences like odors. This also enabled simple
>   matter to exist outside of the holodeck for brief periods of time
>   (such as snow) before they would lose cohesion without the support of
>   the holodeck grid and revert back to energy.
>
> This, however, used an extreme amount of power, and caused repetitive
>   problems to occur in its safe usage. Some time in the mid 24th
>   century, this was slowly phased out in favor of simpler 'true'
>   holographic technology by focusing on the photons contained within
>   micro force fields. This was not only safer and used less power, but
>   had more varied usage and could be easily controlled with quicker
>   reaction times. Some would argue this made it lose its appeal, but
>   advances in the technology has made it as real as the matter
>   replication method, which is still used for more complex, tactile
>   objects, as well as food, odors, etc.